# Teachers asking for money as punishment for being absent

Tags: community-college

I was absent because of some domestic problems so now my teachers are asking me to pay rs.200 as punishment.Is this allowed?

Comment: Are you in elementary school? High school? University?

Comment: Could you add a country tag?

Comment: Please add more background (type of school (university?) / country / your position (student?) )

Comment: I wish I could charge my students for being late !!!

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Almost certainly a south Asian country (rs=rupees).

Comment: When I did my PhD, we had a system where anyone arriving late for our weekly group meeting would pay SEK 20 into a pot.  Once there would be enough money in the pot, we would go out to a pub together.  With the group being populated mainly by Germans, the latter never happened.

Comment: Germans don't go into a pub? ;-)

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Germans are never late.

Comment: @scaaahu - Does this affect the answer?

Comment: I don't see how is this question unclear or out of scope.

Comment: @padawan - Would you join me in voting to reopen?  This is a question that could be faced by students at any level, in principle.

Answer (score 4):

Bring this question to an administrator at your educational institution.  It's helpful to go into something like this with a mental image of yourself as though you were the student's lawyer or advocate -- by this I mean, ask your question in a very neutral tone, without showing any shock or negative *feelings*.